# How can I understand this vector-field?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

We are given a vectorfield $\vec{v}: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ with $\vec{v}(\vec{x})= \|x\|^{\alpha} \vec{x}$ while $\alpha > 0$. Because I missed a lecture, I'm not sure if this is just a vector which has the length of $x$ to the power of $\alpha$ multiplied with every component, or if I'm missing out on some notation. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $\|x\|^\alpha$?

Comment: @Rahul You’re right, it is, I'm sorry. Typing this on my smartphone, so I didn't see preview.

Comment: Do you still have questions, or does correcting the field resolve your doubts?

Comment: @Reveillark It was only a typo while transferring from the script, I'm still not quite sure if I understand the vector field the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying a scalar by a vector will still keep it a vector (i.e. you can define a vector $\vec u$ as $\vec u= 3\vec x$)

Now $\|x\|$ is the "length" of the vector $x$, so it is a scalar (i.e. a number). So you can see $\vec v$ as a function that takes in a vector (for example $\vec x$) and gives you it multiplied by its norm to the power $\alpha$ that is a scalar ( i.e. it gives you $\|x\|^{\alpha}\vec x$)

If there still is a problem, please clarify it more.

Comment: But if I now have to show that rotation is equal to zero, do I take partial derivative of the factor of the components, as well? Or can I just keep the $||x||^{\alpha}$ as a constant?

Comment: If you mean that you want to show that $\vec v$ doesn't rotate $\vec x$, you can simply say that $\vec u$ and $\vec z$ are parellal (i.e. $0$ angle between them) if the relation between them is $\vec u=k\vec z$ where $k$ is a scalar. Another method you can use is to cross multiply the $2$ vectors and you'll get $\vec 0$ is the answer which means that there is a $0^{\circ}$ angle between them.

Comment: To show that $rot \vec{v} = \vec{0}$, as far as I understand, I need to cross with the nabla-operator, which means taking the partial derivatives. When taking those partial derivatives, I asked myself whether I can regard $||\vec{x}||$ as a constant, which would lead to the cross-product being 0 automatically, or if I have to consider $||\vec{x}||$ in my partial derivative.

Comment: Well yes ofcourse you must work with $\|x\|$ as a variable and not a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine your vectors as arrows in 3D space. At every $\vec x$, you're computing the length of $\vec x$ and stretching the arrow by a factor of $\|\vec x\|^\alpha$. As you get further away from the origin, your arrows are longer, so the scaling factor also grows, i.e. you're stretching them even more. So, if you're picturing the arrow $\vec x$, you should picture $v(\vec x)$ as a longer (or shorter, if $\|\vec x\|<1$) arrow put on top of $\vec x$.